# Spring boot 2 in a war file and to deploy in a stand alone tomcat, cannot redirect

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat8

I'm new in using **Spring-boot 2.1.0**,
I'm setting up a new **Spring-boot 2.1.0** web project with maven, in some reasons my front page is **JSP**, and I package the project into a war file.
Then I deploy the war file in a stand alone **Tomcat 8.0**.
I package the war file with the commond `mvn clean package -DskipTest=true`.

The problem is:
The war package name is **marpt**.
login page can access by url http://localhost:8096/marpt, but when I login, action redirect failed, it takes out a 404 error.

I have googled many articles, most are base on Spring-boot 1.x.x version;
I tried to exclude embeded-tomcat in POM file;
And also I tried to config `server.servlet.context-path=/marpt` in the application.properties file, but it's failed to redirect again, and `<%@include file="../../pages/share/partial/sidebar.jsp" %>` failed too, only can use `<jsp:include flush="true" page="/pages/share/partial/sidebar.jsp" />`

I have upload the project to github: [click here](https://github.com/richard20427176/ma-rpt)

I hope some guys can help me to fix it out, thanks very much!

Comment: I don't really get it: you use Spring Boot, which is for stand-alone use, with built-in Tomcat/Jetty/Undertow webserver and you want to deploy it in a separate Tomcat? For me one of the biggest advantages of Spring-Boot is that I don't need a webserver.

Comment: [Sven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7341563/sven) yes, I want to deploy it to a separate Tomcat, with other website together, only use Spring-boot framework to help coding.

Comment: @JacobRichard can please post paste project directory structure here and Also you r main class code so that i can help you out....

Comment: Hi, [Dipak Thoke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5412475/dipak-thoke), thank you for helping me, it've been figured out in another post, see: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54059281/spring-boot-2-1-0-war-file-cannot-config-context-path-or-else-include-in-jsp). I made a mistake with the `<jsp:include page='...' />`